# is it possible to reduce complexity of Grover's algorithm to O(1) from O(root n)?

Tags: grovers-algorithm

[image]

In the above Image:

W = Winning state

S0 = Equal superposition of all possible states

S` = (Equal superposition of all possible states) - (Winning state)

Theta is angle between S0 and S`,

since theta is always going to be very small with bigger dataset, so we need to rotate S0 almost Pi/2 to reach W, so is it possible rotate S0 by pi/2 using [phase gate](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.CPhaseGate.html#qiskit.circuit.library.CPhaseGate) in just 1 go instead of applying combination of oracle+diffuser combination root-N times, though we will end up on other side of W but the possibility of measuring W will be much higher? If at all this is possible then the complexity would come down to 0(1), correct?

**Ques**: is it possible to rotate S0 by Pi/2 using phase gate, if yes then complexity should come down to 0(1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, no -- because the rotation you need depends on the value of $w$, which in turn requires using $U_f$.

It's important to remember the setup of the problem that the Grover algorithm is solving. We assume there exists a function $f: \{ 0, 1, \dots, N-1 \} \rightarrow \{ 0, 1 \}$ such that
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
1 & \text{for } x= w; \\
0 & \text{for } x \neq w, 
\end{cases}$$
for some unknown $w \in \{0, 1, \dots, N-1\}$ which we want to find. We can't query $f$ directly; instead the only tool we have is a *quantum oracle* $U_f$ which is given to us, and we're told is defined by
$$U_f |x\rangle = (-1)^{f(x)} |x\rangle.$$

The Grover algorithm gives us a way of constructing a quantum circuit which finds $w$ with high probability, using only $U_f$ alongside other known quantum gates which don't depend on the function $f$ or the value of $w$.

The issue with your approach is that the standard rotation gates only rotate around *known* axes, e.g. the $R_x(\theta), R_y(\theta)$ and $R_z(\theta)$ gates (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate#Rotation_operator_gates)). Meanwhile, we want to rotate inside a plane which **depends on $w$** -- since your axes $|s'\rangle$ and $|w\rangle$ both depend on $w$ --  whose value we don't know. Hence, in order to construct such a rotation which depends on $w$, we have to use the oracle $U_f$ somehow. This is precisely what the Grover algorithm does, except we find that the best we can do is to break down the rotation into *Grover iterations*, which each uses $U_f$ once and rotates by an angle of much less than $\pi/2$, and we find we need $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{N})$ of them to rotate by the right amount.

I hope that makes sense!